# PHP code inside layout file not executed

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a problem with some PHP code defined at the top of a layout file (default.htm) which does not executes. 
It is just printed verbatim on the page. 
The layout file is the default layout for a plugin. 
Here is the source file (default.htm) :

```
title = "default"
==
<?

use Config;

function onStart() {
    $this['select2_Api_Url'] = Config::get('tudordanes.select2::select2_Api_Url');
}

?>
==
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <div id='my-selects' >
        <label for='select-codes'>Code de loi:</label>
        <select id='select-codes' class='select2' name='select-codes'>
            <option value="">Choisir un code</option>
        </select>
        <label for='select-articles'>Numero:</label>
        <select id='select-articles' name='select-articles'>
            <option value="">Numero d'article</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

{% put scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready!');
        console.log('{{ cfg_API_URL }}');        
</script>    
{% endput %}
```

Comment: Are you accessing the layout file directly via url such as `http://localhost/laravel/layouts/default.htm`? If not, then how is this layout file accessed?

Comment: The path of this file is `\plugins\tudordanes\select2\components\select2\default.htm`. This is the layout file for select2 component defined by select2 plugin.

Comment: If you are visiting `C:\xampp\htdocs\october\plugins\tudordanes\select2\components\select2\default.htm` in your web browser then it's nothing more than a regular HTM file so PHP is never invoked. You need to set up a web server so that the PHP can be executed.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure about this..the file is correctly parsed by OctoberCMS , except that the PHP section is ignored. That's the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your default.htm file is in the component named 'select2' in  'tudordanes' plugin. And the rule is that you cannot access PHP code section in components. Please refer [Building components instructions](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#page-cycle) for the better explanation.

As per code in question, you can do with that is define onRun() function in your Select2.php file.

```
use Config;
public function onRun()
{
    $this->page['select2_Api_Url'] = Config::get('tudordanes.select2::select2_Api_Url');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer! I don't know where exactly is this stated in the docs, but nevermind..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have **and is uncommented** the:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

in your `httpd.conf` file?

"short tags" is a bad habit, if you really need to use them make shure you have and is uncommented:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in your `php.ini`

Comment: October CMS uses templates defined on .htm files that are later converted to PHP code.. or something like that... so no need to configure apache for .htm processing as php code..

Comment: Well the problem wasn't related to httpd.conf settings. Please see the correct answer.